# How to unit test `Thread.currentThread()` in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

So, I recently come across a use-case where i want to unit test `checkNotMainThread` that internally compare `currentThread` and `getMainLooper.thread`. How can we test that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test `checkNotMainThread`. We can use the IoC (Inverse of Control) principle where in runtime we can hook different implementations for a testing environment and production environment.

Image that you have a function where on the function body you add check `checkNotMainThread` that kind of `offensive programming where if the function invocation is utilizing main-thread you wants to crash the app. Do take a look example below.

```kotlin
fun doWork() {
    checkNotMainThread()
    ...
}
```

where implementation detail of `checkNotMainThread` will look like this.

```kotlin
check(
    Thread.currentThread() != Looper.getMainLooper().thread,
    "Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: %s)",
    Thread.currentThread().name
)
```

As you can see here, there's no way around that we can switch the implementation detail by using (i.e Dependency Injection or Service Locator) since both flows are a bit different.

In that case, we can use **IoC Principal** to help us address the requirements. Workflow such as:

1. create a `ThreadCheckerExecutor` class which serves as an entry point for the hook.
2. create a default implementation for ThreadChecker which we can call as `DefaultThreadCheckerExecutor`
3. create a `TestWatcher` that we will use for testing purposes (in this case I give example for JUnit4, for JUnit5 it looks the same.)

**ThreadCheckerExecutor**

```kotlin
/**
 * A static class that serves as a central point to execute common tasks.
 *
 * @hide This API is not final.
 */
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX)
class ThreadCheckerExecutor private constructor() {

    /**
     * By default it will use [DefaultThreadCheckerExecutor]
     */
    internal var threadChecker: ThreadChecker = DefaultThreadCheckerExecutor()

    fun setDelegate(threadChecker: ThreadChecker?) {
        if (threadChecker == null) {
            this.threadChecker = DefaultThreadCheckerExecutor()
        } else {
            this.threadChecker = threadChecker
        }
    }

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        @GuardedBy("lock")
        private var sInstance: ThreadCheckerExecutor? = null
        private val lock = Any()

        @RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX)
        fun getInstance(): ThreadCheckerExecutor {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                synchronized(lock) {
                    if (sInstance == null) {
                        sInstance = ThreadCheckerExecutor()
                    }
                }
            }
            return sInstance!!
        }
    }
}
```

**DefaultThreadCheckerExecutor**

```kotlin
internal class DefaultThreadCheckerExecutor : ThreadChecker {
    override fun checkMainThread() {
        checkState(
            Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().thread,
            "Method cannot be called off the main application thread (on: %s)",
            Thread.currentThread().name
        )
    }

    override fun checkNotMainThread() {
        checkState(
            Thread.currentThread() != Looper.getMainLooper().thread,
            "Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: %s)",
            Thread.currentThread().name
        )
    }
}
```

**MainLooperExecutorRule**

```kotlin
/**
 * A JUnit Test Rule that swaps the background executor used by the call-side with a
 * different one which executes each task synchronously.
 */
class MainLooperExecutorRule : TestWatcher() {
    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        ThreadCheckerExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(object : ThreadChecker {
            override fun checkMainThread() {
                /*No Op*/
            }

            override fun checkNotMainThread() {
                /*No Op*/
            }
        })
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        ThreadCheckerExecutor.getInstance().setDelegate(null)
    }
}
```

**Example on Testing Class**

```kotlin
class Foo {

    @get:Rule
    val rule : MainLooperExecutorRule()

    // some test
}
```

And you're done!